# How to remove unwanted scheme named from SQL Management Studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have nearly 15 SQL Instances names in the Database combobox of SQL Management Studio, now i am using only one and want to remove all the others from that combobox..

They should either be stored in Windows Registry

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you uninstalled the instances?
If they are still in the drop down after that , just search for them in the registry...